# writing to text file - layout messed up - PHP

Tags: php, text, fwrite

ive got the following fwrite code, with , separating the data and it ending in ))

```
$shapeType = $_POST['shapeType'].','.$_POST['triangleSide1'].','.$_POST['triangleSide2']
.','.$_POST['triangleSide3'].','.$_POST['triangleColour'].'))';
fwrite($handle, $shapeType);
```

but this is how it saves in the text file...

> ,,,,))Triangle,180,120,80,Red))

why have the first set of

> ,,,,,))

appeared in front of what it should look like?

Comment: Maybe because you wrote something into that file before...?!

Comment: Come on. This is your third very basic question in 5 minutes that shows absolutely no effort. You don't even attempt to fix your own problems.

Comment: can you post more CODE!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a new line character to the end of each line. Otherwise your lines will all run into each other.

Use [`PHP_EOL`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php) for this as it will automatically use the Operating System appropriate new line character sequence.

> PHP_EOL (string)
>   The correct 'End Of Line' symbol for this platform.
>   Available since PHP 4.3.10 and PHP 5.0.2

```
$shapeType = $_POST['shapeType'].','.$_POST['triangleSide1'].','.$_POST['triangleSide2']
.','.$_POST['triangleSide3'].','.$_POST['triangleColour'].'))'.PHP_EOL;
```

FYI, this might be a little cleaner to do using [`sprintf()`](http://www.php.net/sprintf):

```
$shapeType = sprintf("%s,%s,%s,%s,%s))%s",
    $_POST['shapeType'],
    $_POST['triangleSide1'],
    $_POST['triangleSide2'],
    $_POST['triangleSide3'],
    $_POST['triangleColour'],
    PHP_EOL
);
```

Comment: Sure it will. Why would you think it doesn't? If you find it isn't then your code is telling it not to. But this code only prepares your data for entry.

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing more of the code I would guess that you post to the same file and you do not check if a `POST` request was made before you write your file. So probably you write to your file on a `GET` request as well, causing empty entries to appear.

You would need something like:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')
{
  // ...
  $shapeType = $_POST['shapeType'].','.$_POST['triangleSide1'].','.$_POST['triangleSide2']
.','.$_POST['triangleSide3'].','.$_POST['triangleColour'].'))';
  fwrite($handle, $shapeType);
  // ...
}
```

**Edit:** By the way, you should probably use [`fputcsv`](http://www.php.net/fputcsv) as that takes care of escaping quotes, should you change something in the future that adds for example a description field.

Comment: I think we're both on to something here